# Transaction across multiple EJBs

Tags: java, transactions, ejb, ejb-3.0

Recently refactoring some code, came across transaction rollback scenario where one EJB bean calls another. Now in exception block each bean has its context which is marked for rollback.

Is this a good practice or they should just re-throw the exception & finally the initiator bean only does the rollback.

Also, if there is single transaction spanned across EJB's, then rollback should happen at the originator bean or where it encountered exception.

Transaction type JTA for persistence with XA data source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this

> is marked for rollback

you mean that the EJB catch the exception and use `setRollbackOnly` ?

If that's the case, then it depends on your design to decide which approach is preferred.

Normally a transaction is rolled back if a system exception is detected by the container. Application exception on the opposite does not have this effect.

But, if your business logic require that even a business exception has an important impact such that it must have the effect of rolling back the whole transaction, then you have the choice of `setRollBackOnly`, or launch an application exception with `rollback=true`.

This second approach has also the effect of not destroying the bean.

Regarding your second question:

> Also, if there is single transaction spanned across EJB's, then
>   rollback should happen at the originator bean or where it encountered
>   exception.

the rollback is managed by the container, and again it depends on your design. Keep in mind that the error may pass trough the hole of your unique bean in charge of rolling back the transaction, and not being catched at all. So you will end up with an unwanted scenario with a transaction not being rolled back at all.

Comment: +1 Yes, it's very design specific. But due to some complex scenarios, don't wan't loose things somewhere in between. Also, some other beans might be added in future flow & then they have to track what happens to transaction before & after; therefore thinking that each bean should independently manage without exterior dependency. It's more of a design question & practice to follow.

Comment: Another quite common approach I have often seen, is to catch exception at bean level and re throw an EJBException or a custom exception extending EJBException. That way you can still log what went wrong, and get benefit of container rolling back the transaction.